# Change chart font using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, excel-charts

How do I change the font of an Excel chart using VBA?

If I manually select the chart, and record a macro while I manually change the font name and size, I get the macro below. But when I immediately replay the macro, it throws a run-time error: "The specified value is out of range." So it looks like the macro recorder has a bug. Which means I can't figure out the code to change the font myself.

```
Sub Macro6()
'
' Macro6 Macro
'

'
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").TextFrame2.TextRange.Font
        .NameComplexScript = "Verdana"
        .NameFarEast = "Verdana"
        .Name = "Verdana"
    End With
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 14
End Sub
```

[image]

I know that as an alternative, I could change the font of each individual element one at a time (title, axis titles, axes, ...) but this is tedious and leaves open the possibility of forgetting some elements (series point labels, trendline equations, ...).

I'm looking to change the "default" font of the chart, such that all its elements will have that font.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Indeed that a strange error... Did the same, but I went to the **Object Browser** (F2) with the objective to work around with `Chart` and not `Shape`.

After some trying, I got this one to work :

```
With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Graph").Chart.ChartArea.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font
    .Name = "Verdana"
    .Size = 14
End With
```

It's pretty *simple*, I tried more curious things (as there is a `.Count` property in `TextRange2` class)

It is working just fine and **does change the font of the entire chart**,
you **just have to know the name of your graph**.

Alternatively, make sure the chart is selected, and use `ActiveChart` instead of `ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Graph").Chart`.

Comment: Just chiming in late to say thanks, and to mention that if you get a reference to a shape's .Chart property in PowerPoint, then .ChartArea.Format etc etc lets you access the chart's font properties there too.  Much obliged.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way is:

```
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Font.Name = "Verdana"
```

Comment: This is simple and works, but why does `.Font` not show up in autocomplete after `ChartArea`? It isn't a documented member of the `ChartArea` object. This is rather inconvenient -- and the reason I and the other answerers didn't see this!

Comment: This use is deprecated, so IntelliSense doesn't show it. However, in the Object Browser, if you right click and select Show Hidden Members, you can see Font as a member of ChartArea.

Comment: Most "deprecated" VBA will never go away, since so much legacy code running the world's business relies on deprecated commands.

Answer (score 2):

This was also recorded and works for me (while the chart is selected):

```
Sub Macro1()
    Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 14
    With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font
        .NameComplexScript = "Verdana"
        .NameFarEast = "Verdana"
        .Name = "Verdana"
    End With
End Sub
```

Not really a great difference to your erroneous code.